# How do I change the default/cached thumbnail size?

Tags: product-images

I keep searching for it, but all I get are answers about changing the size on the store page and different views. What I want is to alter the size of cached thumbnail size that I get with

> $product->getThumbnailUrl();

when I upload the new product and Magento creates the small image and thumbnail, not when I retrieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default magento not generate `small_image & thumbnail` on product save/create.

It will create the small_image & thumbnail image only when you try to retrieve it.

If You want to change the resize the thumbnail image just pass the parameter with `$width & $height` in the `getThumbnailUrl` function.

Refer this
[Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::getThumbnailUrl()](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/cb52550f2aa31026dfa9cb95709c567ebe3fded7/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php#L1817-L1820)

**Now anwser for your question :**

To create the thumbail/small image on product creation/save. 
**We can use event observer** `catalog_product_save_after`

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <admin_product_image_resize>
                    <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>imageResize</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </admin_product_image_resize>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

And in `Observer.php` we can force the system to create the thumbnail and small image

```
public function imageResize($observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    try{
        if($product->getSmallImage()){
            (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(150, 150);
        }
        if($product->getThumbnail()){
            (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(80, 80);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        Mage::log($e->getMessage(), null, 'admin-image-resize.log');
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Refer this [Link](http://www.pierrefay.com/event-observers-magento-tutorial-howto-105) for event observer